# Opensearch 2.7 location search using @searchable through graphql

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-opensearch

I'm developing a React Native app using the AWS Amplify GraphQL API. Whenever a user posts, I also capture their latitude and longitude. I'd like to use this data to identify and show other users within a 20-mile radius of that user. I discovered that OpenSearch can help with this, and by adding the @searchable directive to my GraphQL schema and executing 'amplify push', an OpenSearch domain was created for me.

However, I'm unsure of how to search based on the location and specify the radius. Most examples I've found online pertain to ElasticSearch and are not compatible with the version of OpenSearch I'm using, which is 2.7.

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution for this - I want to order data by distance from a given location. I couldn't find any up-to-date examples of how this can be achieved. AWS documentation has some simple examples of how to create a searchable [movie database application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/search-example.html) but couldn't find anything related to location-based search